# How to remove unwanted characters in a file using a shell script

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed, tr

I have a file which looks like this (file.txt)

```
AYOsVS7Wknsgv2StRsEK JBC-ChangeService-Test    CODE_SMELL JBC 97 2022-10-11-10:23 alan.walker@qt.com development [JamesPeter]
AYOsVS7yknsgv2StRsEL JBC-ChangeService-Test    CODE_SMELL JBC 97 2022-10-11-10:23 alan.walker@qt.com development [JamesPeter]
AYOsVS8aknsgv2StRsEM JBC-ChangeService-Test    CODE_SMELL JBC 97 2022-10-11-10:23 alan.walker@qt.com development [JamesPeter]
AYOsVS8hknsgv2StRsEN JBC-ChangeService-Test    CODE_SMELL JBC 97 2022-10-11-10:23 alan.walker@qt.com development [JamesPeter]
AYOsVS8mknsgv2StRsEO JBC-ChangeService-Test    CODE_SMELL JBC 97 2022-10-11-10:23 alan.walker@qt.com development [JamesPeter]
RondomText JBC-ChangeService-Test N/A Coverage(89.1%)     JBC 97 2022-10-11-10:23 alan.walker@qt.com development [JamesPeter]
```

I have to remove unwanted characters in last column
`[JamesPeter]` to `JamesPeter`

then expected output

```
AYOsVS7Wknsgv2StRsEK JBC-ChangeService-Test    CODE_SMELL JBC 97 2022-10-11-10:23 alan.walker@qt.com development JamesPeter
AYOsVS7yknsgv2StRsEL JBC-ChangeService-Test    CODE_SMELL JBC 97 2022-10-11-10:23 alan.walker@qt.com development JamesPeter
AYOsVS8aknsgv2StRsEM JBC-ChangeService-Test    CODE_SMELL JBC 97 2022-10-11-10:23 alan.walker@qt.com development JamesPeter
AYOsVS8hknsgv2StRsEN JBC-ChangeService-Test    CODE_SMELL JBC 97 2022-10-11-10:23 alan.walker@qt.com development JamesPeter
AYOsVS8mknsgv2StRsEO JBC-ChangeService-Test    CODE_SMELL JBC 97 2022-10-11-10:23 alan.walker@qt.com development JamesPeter
RondomText JBC-ChangeService-Test N/A Coverage(89.1%)     JBC 97 2022-10-11-10:23 alan.walker@qt.com development JamesPeter
```

This is what I tried

```
sed 's/[//; s/]//' file.txt
```

then output I got

```
AYOsVS7Wknsgv2StRsEK JBC-ChangeService-Test    CODE_SMELL JBC 97 2022-10-11-10:23 alan.walker@qt.com development [JamesPeter]
AYOsVS7yknsgv2StRsEL JBC-ChangeService-Test    CODE_SMELL JBC 97 2022-10-11-10:23 alan.walker@qt.com development [JamesPeter]
AYOsVS8aknsgv2StRsEM JBC-ChangeService-Test    CODE_SMELL JBC 97 2022-10-11-10:23 alan.walker@qt.com development [JamesPeter]
AYOsVS8hknsgv2StRsEN JBC-ChangeService-Test    CODE_SMELL JBC 97 2022-10-11-10:23 alan.walker@qt.com development [JamesPeter]
AYOsVS8mknsgv2StRsEO JBC-ChangeService-Test    CODE_SMELL JBC 97 2022-10-11-10:23 alan.walker@qt.com development [JamesPeter]
RondomTextJBC-ChangeService-Test N/A Coverage(89.1%)     JBC 97 2022-10-11-10:23 alan.walker@qt.com development [JamesPeter]
```

Can someone help me to figure out this? Thanks in advance!

**Note: I am not allowed to use jq or general-purpose scripting language (JavaScript, Python etc).**

Comment: Can those characters also occur in other places, or only in the last field? BTW: _general-purpose scripting language_ : Isn't `awk` and POSIX shell (which you seem to allow) also a **general purpose** language? How then about zsh or Ruby, for instance?

Comment: @user1934428 awk is a text processing language. idk about JavaScript but python, perl, and ruby all do a lot more than just text processing, they have functionality more like that of shell+awk rather than just awk.

Comment: @EdMorton : Well, all of them are Turing-complete, and awk of curse *can* do numerics. It's just that _general-purpose scripting language_ is not exactly a precisely defined term, and why `jq` is mentioned here as well, escapes my understanding ;-)  At least the OP could try to give a more precise definition of what tools are acceptable and which are not. Or just mention that he only is interested in solutions using the tools which he mentioned in his tags.

Comment: @user1934428 since I am new to scripting, I don't have depth understanding of technical words. my senior asked me to use shell scripting commands like awk, sed etc. he mentioned that avoid using jq or general-purpose scripting languages like javascript, python, ruby etc. because those are not installed in server, and I am not allowed to do any new installations in server. that is why I mentioned it in this question. Is it wrong to mention here or is it gives technical miss leading for you? if anything wrong with **general purpose** term, I am able to remove it.

Comment: It sounds like what you meant was you had to only use mandatory POSIX tools, i.e. the tools that must exist on every Unix system for it to be POSIX compliant. That includes awk, sed, and grep but excludes perl, python, ruby, JavaScript, jq, etc.

Comment: @user1934428 to me, general purpose means it can move/remove files, directories, track process IDs, set up TCP sockets, etc. none of which a POSIX awk can do without running subshells. In other words, the stuff that shell+awk can do together rather than just the stuff that awk can do on it's own.

Comment: @Zero5: As Ed Morton said, POSIX compliancy might be the keyword, but better to ask back for the safe side. In particular, if you would have to restrict yourself to POSIX shell, this would really be a disadvantage. What kind of -nix is the server? Hopefully not something old like SunOS or Unix V. Is there a chance that it has at least bash and/or zsh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `[` and `]` does appear only in last column, then you can delete all `[` and `]` by using `tr` which to my understanding does not count as *general-purpose scripting language*, let `file.txt` content be

```
AYOsVS7Wknsgv2StRsEK JBC-ChangeService-Test    CODE_SMELL JBC 97 2022-10-11-10:23 alan.walker@qt.com development [JamesPeter]
AYOsVS7yknsgv2StRsEL JBC-ChangeService-Test    CODE_SMELL JBC 97 2022-10-11-10:23 alan.walker@qt.com development [JamesPeter]
AYOsVS8aknsgv2StRsEM JBC-ChangeService-Test    CODE_SMELL JBC 97 2022-10-11-10:23 alan.walker@qt.com development [JamesPeter]
AYOsVS8hknsgv2StRsEN JBC-ChangeService-Test    CODE_SMELL JBC 97 2022-10-11-10:23 alan.walker@qt.com development [JamesPeter]
AYOsVS8mknsgv2StRsEO JBC-ChangeService-Test    CODE_SMELL JBC 97 2022-10-11-10:23 alan.walker@qt.com development [JamesPeter]
RondomText JBC-ChangeService-Test N/A Coverage(89.1%)     JBC 97 2022-10-11-10:23 alan.walker@qt.com development [JamesPeter]
```

then

```
tr -d '[]' < file.txt
```

gives output

```
AYOsVS7Wknsgv2StRsEK JBC-ChangeService-Test    CODE_SMELL JBC 97 2022-10-11-10:23 alan.walker@qt.com development JamesPeter
AYOsVS7yknsgv2StRsEL JBC-ChangeService-Test    CODE_SMELL JBC 97 2022-10-11-10:23 alan.walker@qt.com development JamesPeter
AYOsVS8aknsgv2StRsEM JBC-ChangeService-Test    CODE_SMELL JBC 97 2022-10-11-10:23 alan.walker@qt.com development JamesPeter
AYOsVS8hknsgv2StRsEN JBC-ChangeService-Test    CODE_SMELL JBC 97 2022-10-11-10:23 alan.walker@qt.com development JamesPeter
AYOsVS8mknsgv2StRsEO JBC-ChangeService-Test    CODE_SMELL JBC 97 2022-10-11-10:23 alan.walker@qt.com development JamesPeter
RondomText JBC-ChangeService-Test N/A Coverage(89.1%)     JBC 97 2022-10-11-10:23 alan.walker@qt.com development JamesPeter
```

Explanation: I feed `file.txt` to stdin of `tr`, which I instructed to delete following characters: `[`,`]`.

However if `[` and `]` might appear in columns other than last then you might use GNU `AWK` following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
[HelloWorld] 1 [Name]
Hello        2 [Name]
World        3 [Name]
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="[[:space:]]"}{gsub(/\[|\]/,"",$NF);print}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
[HelloWorld] 1 Name
Hello        2 Name
World        3 Name
```

Explanation: I inform GNU `AWK` that field separator (`FS`) is single whitespace character, then for each line I globally (hence `gsub`) replace literal `[` or (`|`) literal `]` using empty string i.e. delete it in last field (`$NF`)

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Answer (score 1):

This `sed` should work to replace `[` and `]` from anywhere in input:

```bash
sed -E 's/[][]//g' file

AYOsVS7Wknsgv2StRsEK JBC-ChangeService-Test    CODE_SMELL JBC 97 2022-10-11-10:23 alan.walker@qt.com development JamesPeter
AYOsVS7yknsgv2StRsEL JBC-ChangeService-Test    CODE_SMELL JBC 97 2022-10-11-10:23 alan.walker@qt.com development JamesPeter
AYOsVS8aknsgv2StRsEM JBC-ChangeService-Test    CODE_SMELL JBC 97 2022-10-11-10:23 alan.walker@qt.com development JamesPeter
AYOsVS8hknsgv2StRsEN JBC-ChangeService-Test    CODE_SMELL JBC 97 2022-10-11-10:23 alan.walker@qt.com development JamesPeter
AYOsVS8mknsgv2StRsEO JBC-ChangeService-Test    CODE_SMELL JBC 97 2022-10-11-10:23 alan.walker@qt.com development JamesPeter
RondomText JBC-ChangeService-Test N/A Coverage(89.1%)     JBC 97 2022-10-11-10:23 alan.walker@qt.com development JamesPeter
```

However if you want to remove `[` and `]` from last field only then use:

```bash
sed -E 's/\[([^]]*)\]$/\1/' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `tr` for this:

```
Prompt> cat file.txt | tr -d "[" | tr -d "]" >result.txt
```

The `-d` switch removes the mentioned character.

Comment: Or simpler, do them both in one fell swoop and avoid a UUOC with `tr -d '[]' < file`

Comment: Also, best not to use same filename for input and output.

Comment: @Cyrus: I've edited my answer and redirected the output to "result.txt" file.